# configure postfix as relay

Tags: postfix, smtp

Since few days I try to configure postfix as relay between exim and enkive. Postfix and enkive are on the one physical server. I see emails in queue of postfix after command mailq but no mail on enkive server.

**master.cf:**

```
8099 inet n - n - - smtpd
 -o content_filter=filter:dummy

filter unix n - n - - pipe
 flags-Rq user=nobody null_sender=  argv=/tmp/Enkive-1.2-CE/support/filters/postfix/enkive-socket-filter/dist/enkive-socket-filter localhost 2527 ${sender} ${reciepient}
```

Can anyone explain me how act transport on postfix?

Comment: What is the output of "postconf"?

Comment: Or, more usefully, what is the output of `postconf -n`? Regardless, you need to show the logs from a complete message, or nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you misspelled "recipient". Could that be it?

Also, the Enkive developers monitor the user mailing list; archives and sign-up available at http://www.enkive.org/community/mailing-list-signup .